# Get commits info of a JIRA issue using REST API

Tags: rest, jira

I am not seeing any commit info in json that I am getting.

https://(jira-instance)/rest/dev-status/latest/issue/detail?issueId=(issueid)&applicationType=stash&dataType=(pullrequest or branch>)

I get only branch, pull request and stash instance info only from these. I also don't see commit info by using

https://(jira-instance)/rest/api/2/issue/(issueid)

Is there anything that I am missing here. Any help will be very useful here

Answer (score 2):

Use dataType=repository. You will get all data including commits.

https://(jira-instance)/rest/dev-status/latest/issue/detail?issueId=(issueid)&applicationType=stash&dataType=repository

Comment: I only get a massive Java stack trace when I try this. BitBucket version 4.9.1. Wonder if this capability was taken away?